# Return of html instead of Json object - python rest api

Tags: python, json, rest, api, jira

It is the first time I have used Python rest api calls. 
The response was successful, the only thing is that I would like to see only a json object rather than html markup. For now I am using this approach:

```
import json

import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth

url = "http://api.url"

myResponse = requests.get(url, auth=HTTPDigestAuth(
    'username', 'password'), verify=True)
if(myResponse.ok):
    print(myResponse.content)
else:
    myResponse.raise_for_status()
```

What comes back is such a thing:

```
b'\n<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang="en">\n<head>\n    \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n<meta charset="utf-8">\n<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>\n<meta name="application-name" content="JIRA" data-name="jira" data-version="8.1.0"><meta name="ajs-server-scheme" content="https">\n<meta name="ajs-server-port" content="443">\n<meta name="ajs-server-name" content="jira.trust-itservices.com">\n<meta name="ajs-behind-proxy" content="null">\n<meta name="ajs-base-url" content="https://jira.trust-itservices.com">\n<meta name="ajs-dev-mode" content="false">\n<meta name="ajs-context-path" content="">\n<meta name="ajs-version-number" content="8.1.0">\n<meta name="ajs-build-number" content="801000">\n<meta name="ajs-is-beta" content="false">\n<meta name="ajs-is-rc" content="false">\n<meta name="ajs-is-snapshot" content="false">\n<meta name="ajs-is-milestone" content="false">\n<meta name="ajs-remote-user" content="">\n<meta name="ajs-remote-user-fullname" content="">\n<meta name="ajs-user-locale" content="en">\n<meta name="ajs-user-locale-group-separator" content=",">\n<meta name="ajs-app-title" content="Trust-IT Jira">\n<meta name="ajs-keyboard-shortcuts-enabled" content="true">\n<meta name="ajs-keyboard-accesskey-modifier" content="Alt">\n<meta name="ajs-enabled-dark-features" content="[&quot;com.atlassian.jira.agile.darkfeature.editable.detailsview&quot;,&quot;nps.survey.inline.dialog&quot;,&quot;com.atlassian.jira.agile.darkfeature.edit.closed.sprint.enabled&quot;,&quot;jira.plugin.devstatus.phasetwo&quot;,&quot;jira.frother.reporter.field&quot;,&quot;atlassian.rest.xsrf.legacy.enabled&quot;,&quot;jira.issue.status.lozenge&quot;,&quot;com.atlassian.jira.config.BIG_PIPE&quot;,&quot;com.atlassian.jira.projects.issuenavigator&quot;,&quot;com.atlassian.jira.config.PDL&quot;,&quot;jira.plugin.devstatus.phasetwo.enabled&quot;,&quot;atlassian.aui.raphael.disabled&quot;,&quot;app-switcher.new&quot;,&quot;frother.assignee.field&quot;,&quot;com.atlassian.jira.projects.ProjectCentricNavigation.Switch&quot;,&quot;jira.onboarding.cyoa&quot;,&quot;com.atlassian.jira.agile.darkfeature.kanplan.enabled&quot;,&quot;com.atlassian.jira.config.ProjectConfig.MENU&quot;,&quot;com.atlassian.jira.projects.sidebar.DEFER_RESOURCES&quot;,&quot;com.atlassian.jira.agile.darkfeature.kanplan.epics.and.versions.enabled&quot;,&quot;com.atlassian.jira.agile.darkfeature.sprint.goal.enabled&quot;,&quot;jira.zdu.admin-updates-ui&quot;,&quot;jira.zdu.jmx-monitoring&quot;,&quot;sd.new.settings.sidebar.location.disabled&quot;,&quot;jira.zdu.cluster-upgrade-state&quot;,&quot;com.atlassian.jira.agile.darkfeature.splitissue&quot;,&quot;com.atlassian.jira.config.CoreFeatures.LICENSE_ROLES_ENABLED&quot;,&quot;jira.export.csv.enabled&quot;]">\n<meta name="ajs-in-admin-mode" content="false">\n<meta name="ajs-is-sysadmin" content="false">\n<meta name="ajs-is-admin" content="false">\n<meta name="ajs-outgoing-mail-enabled" content="true">\n<meta name="ajs-archiving-enabled" content="false">\n<meta name="ajs-date-relativize" content="true">\n<meta name="ajs-date-time" content="h:mm a">\n<meta name="ajs-date-day" content="EEEE h:mm a">\n<meta name="ajs-date-dmy" content="dd/MMM/yy">\n<meta name="ajs-date-complete" content="dd/MMM/yy h:mm a">\n<script type="text/javascript">var AJS=AJS||{};AJS.debug=true;</script>\n\n\n    \n<meta id="atlassian-token" name="atlassian-token" content="BWAC-8WBU-XNHK-O6U3_9eb738dc34edaad0f9eea8dae9a3812ff08af029_lout">\n\n\n\n<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/s/-4jfu5e/801000/6411e0087192541a09d88223fb51a6a0/_/images/fav-jsw.png">\n\n\n    \n\n\n\n
```

It looks like a mixture between html and json, but I want to see only the json that can be seen by opening the browser!

Did I skip using any method?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: *Can* the API return JSON? What does its documentation say?

Comment: I don't know. I want json to return. How should I do?

Comment: Python cannot magically make a json out of anything.  Add headers requesting json from the api and test whether it works, or just read the API's documentation

Comment: It looks like it's not an API endpoint but rather some webpage showing results of the API endpoint you want. That's why it's a webpage with styles and displaying json inside.

Comment: But the strange thing is that if I do view source on the browser, I only see the json I want!

Comment: So as I said: add a header to request json

Comment: I have found the solution and I would like to reopen the question to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach of using `requests` is right. You just have to "simplify" what you wrote if you want to see json. Basically, just try to replace the `requests.get` parameters:

```
response = requests.get(url, auth = ('username', 'password'))

if response.ok:
   jsonContent = response.json()
```